# different treatment of '\' in regex_replace() replacement string in g++ and boost

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, boost

after upgrading gcc from version 4.8.5 to version 5.3.1 I thought I
could get rid of boost's regex-implementation (boost version 1.54.0) and
use the one provided by gcc (it didn't work with gcc before version 4.9
AFAIK). However, this turned out to be a problem because those two
implementations behave differently:

```
#include <regex>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string s="\\needs_another_backslash";
    std::string reg("^(\\\\)(needs)(.+)");
    std::string rep("\\\\got$3");
    std::regex sr(reg);
    boost::regex br(reg);
    std::cout<<"string before replacement:\n"<<s<<std::endl<<
        "regular expression:\n"<<reg<<std::endl<<
        "replacement string:\n"<<rep<<std::endl<<
        "std::regex_replace:\n"<<std::regex_replace(s,sr,rep)<<std::endl<<
        "boost::regex_replace:\n"<<boost::regex_replace(s,br,rep)<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This gives the following output:

`string before replacement:
\needs_another_backslash
regular expression:
^(\\)(needs)(.+)
replacement string:
\\got$3
std::regex_replace:
\\got_another_backslash
boost::regex_replace:
\got_another_backslash`

It seems as if boost treats the '\' in a replacement string specially
whereas gcc does not. Since the magical character for backreference in the replacement string for std::regex_replace is '$' (which it also is in boost as the example proofs), I tend to think that gcc is right. However, in many other programs (like vim e.g.) it is '\'. Therefore, boost might have a point in treating '\' specially. So who is right?

Comment: I don't get how `std::string rep("\\\\got$3");` turns into `\\\\got$3` output (in the first part just displaying values of variables) - I would expect `\\got$3` output (just like `reg` is treated).

Comment: @Ped7g Yes you are right. Sorry. I accidentally copied the output from the program that got it right the boost way. I correct it. Thanks

Comment: To get the same behaviour in `boost` as per `std` implementation, you can use the flag `format_literal` e.g. `boost::regex_replace(text, rgx, fmt, match_flag_type::format_literal)`

Answer (score 1):

First, the std example actually is not a matter of gcc, but of C++ standard, to which gcc (in this case) is compliant. The standard states in 28.5.2:

> When a regular expression match is to be replaced by a new string, the new
>   string shall be constructed using the rules used by the ECMAScript replace
>   function in ECMA-262, part 15.5.4.11 String.prototype.replace. In addition,
>   during search and replace operations all non-overlapping occurrences of the
>   regular expression shall be located and replaced, and sections of the input
>   that did not match the expression shall be copied unchanged to the output
>   string.

And [ECMA](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.4.11) states:

> Otherwise, let newstring denote the result of converting replaceValue to a String. The result is a String value derived from the original input String by replacing each matched substring with a String derived from newstring by replacing characters in newstring by replacement text as specified in Table 22. These $ replacements are done left-to-right, and, once such a replacement is performed, the new replacement text is not subject to further replacements. For example, "$1,$2".replace(/(\$(\d))/g, "$$1-$1$2") returns "$1-$11,$1-$22". A $ in newstring that does not match any of the forms below is left as is.

(If part: replaceValue is a function.)

Nothing mentioned about escape sequences being replaced. Tried out with firefox:

```
var test = "\\needs_another_backslash";
test = test.replace(/^(\\)(needs)(.+)/, "\\\\got$3");
alert(test);
```

Result: `\\got_another_backslash`.

boost [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/match_results.html#boost_regex.match_results_format) states:

> Effects: If fmt is either a null-terminated string, or a container of char_type's, then copies the character sequence [fmt.begin(), fmt.end()) to OutputIterator out. For each format specifier or escape sequence in fmt, replace that sequence with either the character(s) it represents, or the sequence of characters within *this to which it refers. The bitmasks specified in flags determines what format specifiers or escape sequences are recognized, by default this is the format used by ECMA-262, ECMAScript Language Specification, Chapter 15 part 5.4.11 String.prototype.replace.

Additionally, it states for [match_type_flags](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/match_flag_type.html):

> Specifies that when a regular expression match is to be replaced by a new string, that the new string is constructed using the rules used by the ECMAScript replace function in ECMA-262, ECMAScript Language Specification, Chapter 15 part 5.4.11 String.prototype.replace. (FWD.1).
>
> This is functionally identical to the Perl format string rules.
>
> [...]

Tried with perl 5.18.2 on linux:

```
my $test = "\\needs_another_backslash";
$test =~ s/^(\\)(needs)(.+)/\\\\got$3/;
print "$test\n";
```

Resulted in `\\got_another_backslash`.

With `std::string reg("^(\\\\)(needs)(.+)");`, as a string literal is passed, reg holds a string `^(\\)(needs)(.+)` (not a literal, so left out the quotes!), and with `std::string rep("\\\\got$3");`, rep holds `\\got$3`.

But there is obviously a difference in interpretation. Assume we had for both std and boost one and the same ECMAScript engine.

Then, what both std and boost yet do consistently, is compiling the `reg` string as regular expression:

```
sprintf(b, "/%s/", reg);
sr /* br, respectively */ = ECMAScriptEngine::compileFromSource(b);
```

I think this is reflected quite nicely by creating an instance of std/boost::regex class.

Then comes the difference, however: std passes `s`, `sr` and `rep` to the ECMAScript engine such that it calls directly `s.(String.prototype.replace)(sr, rep);` (of course there is no such  function for s in reality – just lets assume we could do it this way).

boost lets compile the rep string, too (side note: I haven't installed boost, so I did not verify this behaviour myself...):

```
sprintf(b, "'%s'", rep); // note: '', not //!
ecma_rep = ECMAScriptEngine::compileFromSource(b);
```

and then makes the engine call `s.(String.prototype.replace)(sr, ecma_rep);`.

Interestingly, boost does not compile the source string s, where it again agrees with std...

In the end, I think, however, the standard implementation reflects closer what we actually want to do:

```
s.replace(regex, string);
s.replace(/reg/, rep);
(std::string).replace(std::regex(std::string), std::string);
std::regex_replace(s, std::regex(reg), rep);
```

vs

```
s.replace(regex, string);
s.replace(/reg/, "rep");
(std::string).replace(boost::regex(std::string), boost::???(std::string));
boost::regex_replace(s, boost::regex(reg), rep); // not boost::???(rep)!
```

Not sure if this is sufficient to say one is right and the other wrong, however (would mean that the wrong one is buggy!). Possibly we even have to remain with a third option: Both approaches are valid (so both are right and none is wrong) and, unfortunately, they are incompatible...

Comment: I aggree that std::regex_replace is standard and not gcc. But I deliberately put it that way to stress that this is the gcc version of the standard. (What about other compilers?) This is the whole point of the question: which version is standard conformant? Since there seems to be no mentioning of any speciality of the backslash in the replacement string, I am more inclined to think gcc is right. In my opinion there must be an answer to "Which is correct version?" How can there be two correct implementations yielding different results? After all, this is not undefined behaviour, ;-)

Comment: @diffset Just wait a second - boost is not the standard! If you compared gcc against clang or msvc and you had differences when using the standard regex library -- *then* you could argue that one is right and another one not. boost must be considered a competing library (although it had great influences on the standard) instead of an implementation of the standard and in this respect is quite well allowed to do this or that differently.

Comment: @diffset An example: Imagine you implement your own version of a vector - dropping the requirement of contiguous memory as you do not need it (and some other stuff in this respect), allowing to implement a more performant reallocation algorithm (adding new junks to the existing ones instead of reallocating *everything*). Of course, this would not conform the standard - but it isn't an implementation of the standard either. So as long as you do not pretend to be the standard, everything is fine (true, boost's regex_replace shares the name, but in a different namespace: `boost` and not `std`).

Comment: I aggree. Boost is not standard. But on the other hand I (and you obviously neither) couldn't find any reference to the special character of '\' in the rep string, be it standard or boost documentation. The only reason to treat it specially would be if it had a special meaning. Which it doesn't. In those languages where it is the backref character, it must be escaped, like in MySQL: `select regexp_replace("\\needs_another_backslash", "^(\\\\)(needs)(.+)", "\\\\got\\3");`. But why here. Does perl explain that? I am not familiar with that langauge.

Comment: @diffset Perl is different in this respect as in this language, you have the replacement packed into one single regex: `s/pattern/replacement/`. If you now write this as a literal, of course both pattern and replacement need to be escaped. This was my idea for the analogy. But forget about perl, I have a better idea to explain...

Comment: Okay, I see. But then there is a good reason to escape the backslash in perl. But with c++ (boost) one can also ask why does the backslash need to be escaped whereas parentheses don't. When I change the rep string literal from "\\\\got$3" to "\\\\(got)$3" the parentheses appear in the output in both versions.

Comment: Be aware that any escape sequence "\x" where x is one of the defined characters with special meaning ('n' = newline, 't' = tab, ...) is escaped to 'x' (both C++ and ECMAScript). For ordinary strings (not regular expressions!), "\\(" is no special escape sequence, so "\\\\(" as literal would result in a string containing `\(`. Of course, you would see the parenthesis in both versions. But for std, you get `\(` as replacement, whereas for boost, you should then see the parenthesis *only*, and no backslash. If you didn't, you would have proven my answer wrong, at least partially.

Comment: I was referring to your compilation approach. Yo said that in boost both regex and rep strings will be compiled whereas in std rep was left untouched. If that were the case why would we see the parentheses in boost at all? Unfortunately I erased one backslash in my example last comment. So for simplicity let rep="(got)$3". If this is indeed compiled the parens should be gone because in regex they are used to group things. Side note: Why do I get this warning: `warning: unknown escape sequence: '\)' in std::string rep("\\\(got\\\)$3");` but not for the opening paren

Comment: Ah, here we go. Have a very close look at both sprintf calls. For the first, pattern is `"/%s/"`, whereas for the second, it is `"'%s'"` (could have been `"\"%s\""` as well, would have been equivalent). See the difference? First time, we compile a regex literal, second time, a string literal...

Comment: By the way: this is why I used `boost::???` in my conclusion (to denote that it is an internal class unknown to us representing the compiled string literal), explicitly not `boost::regex`. And this goes parallel with perl, too - in the replacement string, you do not have to escape parentheses any more either.