# Conditionally replace regex matches in string

Tags: c++, regex, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, c++11

I am trying to replace certain patterns in a string with different replacement patters.

Example:

```
string test = "test replacing \"these characters\"";
```

What I want to do is replace all ' ' with '_' and all other non letter or number characters with an empty string.  I have the following regex created and it seems to tokenize correctly, but I am not sure how to (if possible) perform a conditional replace using `regex_replace`.

```
string test = "test replacing \"these characters\"";
regex reg("(\\s+)|(\\W+)");
```

expected result after replace would be:

```
string result = "test_replacing_these_characters";
```

EDIT:
I cannot use boost, which is why I left it out of the tags. So please no answer that includes boost. I have to do this with the standard library. It may be that a different regex would accomplish the goal or that I am just stuck doing two passes.

EDIT2:
I did not remember what characters were included in `\w` at the time of my original regex, after looking it up I have further simplified the expression. Again the goal is anything matching \s+ should be replaced with '_' and anything matching \W+ should be replaced with empty string.

Comment: Why did you drop the last `"`-char in your example output?

Comment: @rubberboots - because only white space should be replaced with an underscore, any other non letter and digit character should be replaced with nothing.

Comment: I see, so you'll want to have different replacement texts in one pass. This won't work afaik in c++ regex. If somebody nows a trick for this, I'd like to use that too ;-)

Comment: @rubberboots - Yep, that is the reason for my question and I figure I will end up finding out - "You can't do that", but I figured I could ask and hope that somebody smart would have a solution.

Comment: I found a method with callback functions that, unfortunately, isn't actually working in my C++11 implementation (g++ 4.6.1, VS2012) (but works in boost).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The c++ (0x, 11, tr1) regular expressions [do not really work (stackoverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4716680/170194) in every case (look up the [phrase **regex** on **this page**](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.200x) for gcc), so it is better to [use boost](http://www.boost.org/libs/regex/) for a while.

You may try if your compiler supports the regular expressions needed:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    string test = "test replacing \"these characters\"";
    regex reg("[^\\w]+");
    test = regex_replace(test, reg, "_");
    cout << test << endl;
}
```

The above works in Visual Studio 2012Rc.

**Edit 1**: To replace by **two different strings** in one pass (depending on the match), I'd think this won't work here. In Perl, this could easily be done within evaluated replacement expressions (`/e` switch).

Therefore, you'll need two passes, as you already suspected:

```
 ...
 string test = "test replacing \"these characters\"";
 test = regex_replace(test, regex("\\s+"), "_");
 test = regex_replace(test, regex("\\W+"), "");
 ...
```

**Edit 2**:

If it would be possible to use a **callback function** `tr()` in `regex_replace`, then you could modify the substitution there, like:

```
 string output = regex_replace(test, regex("\\s+|\\W+"), tr);
```

with `tr()` doing the replacement work:

```
 string tr(const smatch &m) { return m[0].str()[0] == ' ' ? "_" : ""; }
```

the problem would have been solved. Unfortunately, there's **no such overload** in some C++11 regex implementations, but Boost **[has one](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/regex-Context-sensitive-replacement-of-text-using-regex-replace-tp2589269p2589275.html)**. The following would work with boost and use one pass:

```
...
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
using namespace boost;
...
string tr(const smatch &m) { return m[0].str()[0] == ' ' ? "_" : ""; }
...

string test = "test replacing \"these characters\"";
test = regex_replace(test, regex("\\s+|\\W+"), tr);   // <= works in Boost
...
```

Maybe some day this will work with C++**11** or whatever number comes next.

Regards

rbo

Comment: I don't want to replace " with underscore, it should be replaced with nothing. That is the crux of my issue, I want to replace the first match group with _ and the second match group with empty string. I should also have mentioned that I cannot use boost.

Comment: Your second edit that runs in VS2012 still does not solve my issue. The whitespace must be replaced with _ and all other non letter and number characters must be replaced with empty string

Comment: The two-pass version does this on my system, the result is `test_replacing_these_characters`.

Answer (score -1):

The way to do this has commonly been accomplished by using four backslashes to remove the backlash effecting the actual C code. Then you will need to make a second pass for the parentheses and escape them in your regex then and only then.

```
string tet = "test replacing \"these characters\"";
//regex reg("[^\\w]+");
regex reg("\\\\"); //--AS COMMONLY TAUGHT AND EXPLAINED
tet = regex_replace(tet, reg, " ");
cout << tet << endl;

regex reg2("\""); //--AS SHOWN
tet = regex_replace(tet, reg2, " "); 
cout << tet << endl;
```

And in a single pass use;

```
string tet = "test replacing \"these characters\"";
//regex reg("[^\\w]+");
regex reg3("\\\""); //--AS EXPLAINED
tet = regex_replace(tet, reg3, "");
cout << tet << endl;
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. The question was whether there was a way (back in 2012) for me to replace all space characters with underscores and all non letter and number characters with the empty string. I was hoping to do it in a single pass. Your answer also does not output the correct result which is: test_replacing_these_characters