# How to find and replace all characters in a string with specific symbols C++

Tags: c++, replace

I am a beginner in programming so take it easy if i approached the problem in a wrong way. i am doing this as an assignment. My purpose is to take a string from user and replace all the characters with another symbol. The code below is supposed to find all the As and replace then with *s. My code is showing totally unexpected result. Also what is the purpose of _deciphered.length().

for example:
"I Am A bAd boy" should turn into "I *m * b*d boy"

then i am supposed to implement it for all capital and small letters and numbers and replace with different symbols and vice versa to make a small Encode-Decode program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
string cipher (string);
void main ()
{

    string ciphered, deciphered;
    ciphered="String Empty";
    deciphered="String Empty";
    cout<<"Enter a string to \"Encode\" it : ";
    cin>>deciphered;
    ciphered=cipher (deciphered);
    cout<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<deciphered;
}
string cipher (string _deciphered)
{
    string _ciphered=(_deciphered.replace(_deciphered.find("A"), _deciphered.length(), "*"));
    return _ciphered;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you seem to be using the standard library already,

```
#include <algorithm> // for std::replace

std::replace(_deciphered.begin(), _deciphered.end(), 'A', '*');
```

If you need to do this by hand, then bear in mind that an `std::string` looks like a container of `char`, so you can iterate over its contents, check if each element is `'A'`, and if so, set it to `'*'`.

Working example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
  std::string s = "FooBarro";
  std::cout << s << std::endl;
  std::replace(s.begin(), s.end(), 'o', '*');
  std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

> FooBarro
>
> F**Barr*

Comment: this only works till it finds first a and returns only that word. eg if i enter "bad bay" it returns "b*d". how do i get it to return complete string "b*d b*y"?

Comment: @UsamaKhurshid no, you are mistaken. It will replace all `A` characters by `*`.

Comment: @UsamaKhurshid I tried it. Either you are trying something else or your std library implementation is broken.

Comment: the solution that u posted now works! thanks.. i wonder what was wrong with the first one you posted!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::replace`

```
std::replace(deciphered.begin(), deciphered.end(), 'A', '*');
```

Also, you can use `std::replace_if` if you want to replace multiple values that match a certain criteria.

```
std::replace_if(deciphered.begin(), deciphered.end(), myPredicate, '*');
```

where `myPredicate` returns `true` if the character matches the criteria to be replaced. So for example, if you want to replace both `a` and `A`, `myPredicate` should return `true` for `a` and `A` and false for other characters.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally use regular experssion replace to repace "A or a" with *

Have a look at this answer for some pointers: [Conditionally replace regex matches in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508798/conditionally-replace-regex-matches-in-string)

Comment: While a regular expression could be used, `std::replace` is much simpler and has much less overhead.