# Regex to replace all occurrences between two matches

Tags: c++, regex, std

I am using `std::regex` and need to do a search and replace.

**The string I have is:**

```
begin foo even spaces and maybe new line(
some text only replace foo foo bar foo, keep the rest
)
some more text not replace foo here
```

Only the stuff between `begin .... (` and `)` should be touched.

**I manage to replace the first foo by using this search and replace:**

```
(begin[\s\S]*?\([\s\S]*?)foo([\s\S]*?\)[\s\S]*)

$1abc$2
```

**[Online regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xM3yQ6/1)**

**[Online C++ demo](http://cpp.sh/4rdm)**

However, **how do I replace all three foo in one pass?** I tried lookarounds, but failed because of the quantifiers.

**The end result should look like this:**

```
begin foo even spaces and maybe new line(
some text only replace abc abc bar abc, keep the rest
)
some more text not replace foo here
```

**Question update:**

I am looking for a pure regex solution. That is, the question should be solved by only changing the `search` and `replace` strings in [the online C++ demo](http://cpp.sh/4rdm).

Comment: What should the end result look like?

Comment: Maybe it would be easier to get the text between brackets and do a replace all? Then you reconstruct the string.

Comment: @Thomas there is, read closely.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot damn wrong copy/paste. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with this code (based on [Benjamin Lindley's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22617942/3832970)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>
int main()
{
    std::string input_text = "my text\nbegin foo even 14 spaces and maybe \nnew line(\nsome text only replace foo foo bar foo, keep the rest\n)\nsome more text not replace foo here";
    std::regex re(R"((begin[^(]*)(\([^)]*\)))");
    std::regex rxReplace(R"(\bfoo\b)");
    std::string output_text;
    auto callback = [&](std::string const& m){
        std::smatch smtch;
        if (regex_search(m, smtch, re)) {
            output_text += smtch[1].str();
            output_text += std::regex_replace(smtch[2].str().c_str(), rxReplace, "abc");
        } else {
            output_text += m;
        }
    };

    std::sregex_token_iterator
        begin(input_text.begin(), input_text.end(), re, {-1,0}),
        end;
    std::for_each(begin,end,callback);

    std::cout << output_text;
    return 0;
}
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/TJsGfH)

I am using one regex to find all matches of `begin...(....)` and pass them into the callback function where only Group 2 is processed further (a `\bfoo\b` regex is used to replace `foo`s with `abc`s).

I suggest using `(begin[^(]*)(\([^)]*\))` regex:

- `(begin[^(]*)` - Group 1 matching a character sequence `begin` followed with zero or more characters other than `(`
- `(\([^)]*\))` - Group 2 matching a literal `(` followed with zero or more characters other than `)` (with `[^)]*`) and a literal `)`.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I am looking for a pure regexp solution. I already worked around this in code, but I would prefer to have all logic in one regex. I'll update my question to make it clearer. But nice solution anyway!

Comment: It is not possible to do with std::regex. It does not support \G operator, nor does it support an infinite width lookbehind.