# C++ Regex Iterator Returning Strange Results, Despite Correct Expression

Tags: c++, regex, xml

I am reading/modifying an XML file line by line, and I run into some problems when trying to identify some variables.

For example, I have two lines:

I have the following regex pattern:
[image]

And the following code:
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/56c1eeab034c3b92

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string var = "<bt x=\"1.32857e06\" y=\"1.15418e06\" bit=\"2\" mat=\"3\"/>";

    const regex r("(\\w+)(?:\\s*=\\s*\")(\\d+(?:.\\d+e[+-]?\\d+)?)(?:\")");
    auto words_begin = sregex_iterator(var.begin(),var.end(), r);
    auto words_end = sregex_iterator();
    bool dontWrite = true;
    size_t position;
    smatch sm;

    for (sregex_iterator i = words_begin; i != words_end; ++i)
    {
        sm = *i;
        string match_str = sm.str();
        if (regex_match(match_str, sm, r))
        {
            if (sm[1] == "mat")
            {
                dontWrite = false;
            }
            position = var.find(sm[2]);
            if ((sm[1] == "xmin")||(sm[1] == "x"))
            {
                var.replace(position,sm[2].length(),to_string(1.01));
            }
            else if ((sm[1] == "ymin")||(sm[1] == "y"))
            {
                var.replace(position,sm[2].length(),to_string(1.02));
            }
            cout << "piece: " << sm[1] << ", " << sm[2] << ", dontWrite: " << dontWrite << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

What I expect to cout is:

```
piece: x, 1.32857e06, dontWrite: 1
piece: y, 1.15418e06, dontWrite: 1
piece: bit, 2, dontWrite: 1
piece: mat, 3, dontWrite: 0
```

But for some reason, I don't see the second line.  This isn't the only configuration that hasn't worked for me.  Other times, it matches both "mat" and "at".  I've had cases where it matches 4 out of 6 of what it should match.  If I take away the position variable, I get the expected output (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/51e6b2ba279407a3), but I need that variable for later (to replace the values of certain attributes).

I am out of ideas for why this is the case, and would like to hear what you all have to say.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I see that I have Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 - 2015 Redistributable listed in Programs and Features.  So I guess that means I'm using VC++ 2015?  But I'm compiling it from Visual Studio Express 2013 and Qt Creator 5.8.  Both compilers are yielding the same results.

Comment: I do not understand why you run `if (regex_match(match_str, sm, r))` - you already have the filled  `smatch` there. Also, note that an unescaped `.` in your pattern matches any char, not just a dot.

Comment: Good point!  I made the change, but I'm still getting the same results...

Comment: Perhaps, because you change `var` in-place, while still iterating over the matches. After you replace a longer `x="1.32857e06"` with a shorter `x="1.010000"`, the index is still a bit farther to the right, so `y` is not matched. You need a kind of a replace callback approach here.

Comment: I see, so something similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22617209/regex-replace-with-callback-in-c11