# Replace tag1 tag2 tag3 for x1 x2 x3

Tags: c++, regex

I'm very new to regex and C++, so please be easy on me :) !

Given a string like this one:

Input:

```
string s = "<ph0/>Hello StackOverflow! Thank you for helping! <ph1/>"
```

I want to replace the ph1 and ph2 tags for __ent_00000_ and __ent_00001_ respectively, so in the end I'd like my output to be:
Output:

```
string s = "__ent_00000_Hello StackOverflow! Thank you for helping! __ent_00001_"
```

And I also would like to do the reverse i.e:

Input:

```
string s = "__ent_00000_Bye bye StackOverflow!  __ent_00001_"
```

Output:

```
string s = "<ph0/>Bye bye StackOverflow!  <ph1/>"
```

This would be for any arbitrary number of tags in a string! So the idea here is to simply replace but keep the number intact!

My idea was to regex_replace ([documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_replace/)) but
maybe there's another way,I'm open to any other solution that works!

Example with multiple tags:

Input:

```
string input = "Restaurant is closed<ph0/> <ph1/> <ph2/> <ph3/> | <ph4/> <ph5/>alert<ph6/>We are not serving meals<ph7/> <ph8/> <ph9/> <ph10/> | <ph11/> <ph12/>sorry!"
```

Output:

```
string output = "Restaurant is closed__ent_00000_ __ent_00001_ __ent_00002_ __ent_00003_ | __ent_00004_ __ent_00005_alert__ent_00006_We are not serving meals__ent_00007_ __ent_00008_ __ent_00009_ __ent_00010_ | __ent_00011_ __ent_00012_sorry!"
```

Thank you and have a nice day! :)

Comment: What have you tried so far? What's wrong with regex_replace?

Comment: Nothing! It's probably the right approach! I just can't get the pattern with the subgroups right, actually I don't even know how to start, I don't know this regex engine !

Comment: Can you add an example with multiple tags in the string?

Comment: Yes! Sure give me a sec

Comment: Added a new example with 12 tags

Answer (score 2):

You are setting yourself up for failure if your first solution to this problem involves regular expressions. **Please don't!** (where a simple string replace will suffice).

If each tag occurs only once, all you really need to do is call [`string::replace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/replace) on them. Even if they occur multiple times, using boost's [`replace_all()`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/doc/html/boost/algorithm/replace_all.html) algorithm.

Comment: But to find out the number of tags I'd have to do regex_match with a pattern, no ? Or how would you do it?

Comment: Why would you like to find the tags? Simply attempt a replace, it nothing matches it is a no-op.

Comment: But then I;d have to still find the positions for every tag, how would I do that? I've been searching and I'm just  getting more confused ...

Comment: Yeah you were right this was not that complicated, regex would be unnecessary !

Comment: You know what everyone (not, unfortunately) says about regex? "Someone: I have a problem. Everyone: Use regex. You: Now you have two problems."

Answer (score 1):

The first case is really a scenario C++ regex is not quite capable to handle out-of-the-box due to the fact you need to replace the capture in Group 1 with a zero left-padded number. It requires a callback, and this [may be implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37516316/3832970) like this:

```
template<class BidirIt, class Traits, class CharT, class UnaryFunction>
std::basic_string<CharT> regex_replace(BidirIt first, BidirIt last,
    const std::basic_regex<CharT,Traits>& re, UnaryFunction f)
{
    std::basic_string<CharT> s;

    typename std::match_results<BidirIt>::difference_type
        positionOfLastMatch = 0;
    auto endOfLastMatch = first;

    auto callback = [&](const std::match_results<BidirIt>& match)
    {
        auto positionOfThisMatch = match.position(0);
        auto diff = positionOfThisMatch - positionOfLastMatch;

        auto startOfThisMatch = endOfLastMatch;
        std::advance(startOfThisMatch, diff);

        s.append(endOfLastMatch, startOfThisMatch);
        s.append(f(match));

        auto lengthOfMatch = match.length(0);

        positionOfLastMatch = positionOfThisMatch + lengthOfMatch;

        endOfLastMatch = startOfThisMatch;
        std::advance(endOfLastMatch, lengthOfMatch);
    };

    std::sregex_iterator begin(first, last, re), end;
    std::for_each(begin, end, callback);

    s.append(endOfLastMatch, last);

    return s;
}

template<class Traits, class CharT, class UnaryFunction>
std::string regex_replace(const std::string& s,
    const std::basic_regex<CharT,Traits>& re, UnaryFunction f)
{
    return regex_replace(s.cbegin(), s.cend(), re, f);
}

std::string callback_to(const std::smatch& m) {
    stringstream s;
    char buffer[6];
    sprintf(buffer, "%05d", stoi(m.str(1)));
    s << "__ent_" << buffer << "_";
    return s.str();
}
```

Then, inside the main code, you may use it like

```
std::string s = "Restaurant is closed<ph0/> <ph1/> <ph2/> <ph3/> | <ph4/> <ph5/>alert<ph6/>We are not serving meals<ph7/> <ph8/> <ph9/> <ph10/> | <ph11/> <ph12/>sorry!";
std::regex reg_to("<ph(\\d+)/>");
std::cout << regex_replace(s, reg_to, callback_to) << std::endl;
// => Restaurant is closed__ent_00000_ __ent_00001_ __ent_00002_ __ent_00003_ | __ent_00004_ __ent_00005_alert__ent_00006_We are not serving meals__ent_00007_ __ent_00008_ __ent_00009_ __ent_00010_ | __ent_00011_ __ent_00012_sorry!
```

The regex is simple, `<ph(\d+)/>`, matching `<ph`, 1+ digits captured in Group 1, and then `/>`. Inside the callback method, `char buffer[6]; sprintf(buffer, "%05d", stoi(m.str(1)));` will prep the number and `s << "__ent_" << buffer << "_";` will get the string steam filled with the necessary data.

The opposite replacement is simple and straight-forward:

```
std::string t = "__ent_00000_Bye bye StackOverflow!  __ent_00001_";
std::regex reg_from("__ent_0*(\\d+)_");
std::cout << std::regex_replace(t, reg_from, "<ph$1/>") << std::endl;
// => <ph0/>Bye bye StackOverflow!  <ph1/>
```

The `__ent_0*(\d+)_` pattern matches `__ent_`, then zero or more `0` chars, then captures 1+ digits into Group 1 and then `_` is matched. The replacement is `<ph` + Group 1 value, and `/>` text.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2EN8zp/1).