# Remove text between two characters (parenthesis) in a string

Tags: c++, string

I'm working on a project and I want to remove text between two parentheses in a string.
Example:

```
std::string str = "I want to remove (this)."
```

How would I go about doing that?
I've searched google and stackoverflow an haven't found anything.

Comment: Parts of one approach: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/erase/ , http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/

Comment: What about nested parentheses, multiple parentheses, ... ? Basically this is a simple search.

Comment: You can use `std::regex`,  but that may depend on your real use case.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a regular expression for that. Check out the link I provided. As for the expression to use the following expression

`(\()(?:[^\)\\]*(?:\\.)?)*\)`

That guy worked for me.

[Conditionally replace regex matches in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508798/conditionally-replace-regex-matches-in-string)

- Do not get regular and common expressions confused. This is not like the more common expression of `:-)` or `:-O` or `>:(` All-though effective These expressions are mutually exclusive expressions that not many languages understand but are more commonly used.

Comment: What happend here if the value is the following: std::string str = "I want to remove (this (one))." and I would like to have as a result "I want to remove "