# Regex in C++: Requires compiler support error

Tags: c++, regex, compiler-construction

I'm trying to use `regex` in C++. The following is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<regex>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    string A = "Hello!";
    regex pattern = "(H)(.*)";
    if (regex_match(A, pattern)) {
        cout << "It worked!";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But I'm encountering this error :

```
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.5.3/include/c++/regex:35:0,
                 from main.cpp:12:
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.5.3/include/c++/bits/c++0x_warning.h:31:2: error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the upcoming ISO C++ standard, C++0x. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x compiler options.
```

How can this be solved and what is wrong?

Comment: well the fix is already specified in the error itself...

Comment: Perhaps dup to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716680/c0x-regex-in-gcc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> and must be enabled with the -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x compiler options

Add one of those options, `-std=c++0x` or `-std=gnu++0x`, to your compiler command:

> g++ -std=c++0x ...

Note if `std::regex` is not supported see [`boost::regex`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html) for an alternative.

Comment: How exactly do I do that? Thanks!

Comment: Oh. I'm not using the terminal to compile and run my code. I'm using netbeans.

Comment: @Enigman, I don't use NetBeans. Google for how to add compiler options in NetBeans or search the NetBeans manual should provide you with a solution.

Comment: Yeah. I shouldn't have asked that here! Sorry. Will do that.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are trying to use the regex class, which is part of the new C++11 standard, but not telling the compiler to compile to that standard.

Add  -std=c++0x  to your compiler flags and try again.

EDIT : As [the gcc implementation status page](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.200x) shows, the regex support in gcc is far from complete. So even adding the right flag wont help yet. If you need regex support, you could try [boost](http://www.boost.org/).

Comment: How do I add it to my 'compiler flags?' I'm using NetBeans. Is there an option here that lets me do that?

Comment: project properties -> Build -> C++ Compiler -> Additional Options I believe.

Comment: I've done that. Still there seems to be error. :( I tried the code given at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_match/ too.

Comment: See my edit. Regex support in the gcc C++11 implementation is not complete.

Comment: @Enigman - don't bother. GCC's implementation of regular expressions is unusable.

Answer (score 2):

Simply just add

```
g++ -std=gnu++0x <filename.cpp>
```

or

```
g++ -std=c++0x <filename.cpp>
```

It will work properly