# using regex under c++11

Tags: c++, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++0x regex in GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716680/c0x-regex-in-gcc)

I was trying to transform a file under c++ using regex, some regex_error keeps on occuring, 
here is the code:

```
std::ifstream inf(in);
std::ofstream outf(out);
try{
std::regex line_regex("[[:alnum:]]");
std::string line;
while(std::getline(inf,line))
{
    if(std::regex_match(line,line_regex))
        outf<<line<<std::endl;
}
```

the error message is:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::regex_error'
what():  regex_error
```

by the way, I'm using gcc 4.7.2 on linux x64.

Comment: gcc version 4.6.1 had only partial support for std::regex, I don't know if it has been fixed in version 4.7.0 yet, on second thought I think they haven't fixed it check for regex in here http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2011

Comment: I tried `std::regex` on 4.6.2 and couldn't get it to work either.  Ended up wrapping PCRE instead.  I think the Perl regex syntax is the best and most expressive and PCRE is an extremely stable time-honored library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GCC's implementation of `<regex>` is unusable. Don't waste your time on it.

Comment: Yes,I use the boost version instead, it works fine.

Comment: @flyingfoxlee - as does the Microsoft version.