# regex in g++ and VS2012

Tags: c++, regex, visual-studio-2012, g++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

void Test(const char* str, const char* regExpression)
{
    regex rx(regExpression);
    bool match = regex_match(str, rx);
    bool search = regex_search(str, rx);

    cout << "String: " << str << "  expression: " << regExpression <<
        "   match: " << (match ? "yes" : "no ") <<
        "   search: " << (search ? "yes" : "no ")  << endl;
}


int main()
{
    Test("a", "a");
    Test("a", "abc");
    return 0;
}
```

Results in g++:

```
String: a  expression: a   match: yes   search: no 
String: a  expression: abc   match: no    search: no
```

Results in VS2012:

```
String: a  expression: a   match: yes   search: yes
String: a  expression: abc   match: no    search: no
```

What is correct result?. Also, what is the difference between regex_match and regex_search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The VS2012 results are right. `_match` checks whether your string matches the expression, `_search` checks whether some substring of your string matches the expression.

Neither `"a"` nor any substring of `"a"` match the expression `"abc"`.

(I can't find the relevant SO question, but gcc's (rather, libstdc++'s) regex implementation is known to be buggy and incomplete.)

Comment: Shame on me, I just used Test parameters in incorrect order :(

Comment: No need for an SO question; it's described on the [standard library support table for GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.200x) (see '28, Regular expressions')

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12530406/is-gcc4-7-buggy-about-regular-expressions/12665408#12665408 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/4716974/981959 and loads more questions