# strange behaviour of regex in c++11 under linux

Tags: regex, linux, c++11

I've been sitting here for nearly a day now and cannot figure out, why the C++11 regex library gives me the output it does. It is not about finding the pattern, I already designed and tested it in various regex-testers out there. ([Regexpal](http://regexpal.com/) for example)

An example string I want to process would be:

```
if12b031, if12b141, ic12a042
```

These are usernames, containing letters and numbers at a maximum length of 8 characters, each username septerated by a comma. The string is entered by the user and must not end with a comma. The spaces between the commas are optional.

This pattern was my approach to solve this problem:

```
^[A-z0-9]{1,8}(\s*,\s*[A-z0-9]{1,8})*$
```

Here the user has to enter a least 1 username, but can enter as many as he wants, as long as they are seperated by comma and have a maximum length of 8 characters.

Now the strang thing is, this pattern works, if I test it in the regex-tester mentioned above. But it doesn't in my code.

I've created a small example program, where it is only about pattern testing.

```
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
string tmp;
string pattern = "^[A-z0-9]{1,8}(\\s*,\\s*[A-z0-9]{1,8})*$";

while(true)
{
    getline(cin, tmp);

    cout << "input: " << tmp << endl;
    cout << "pattern: " << pattern << endl;

    try {
        if(regex_match(tmp, regex(pattern, std::regex_constants::basic))) {
            cout << "match" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "no match" << endl;
        }
    } catch (std::regex_error& e) {
        cout << e.code() << endl;
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

I compiled using the following code:

```
c++ -std=c++11 -o test test.cpp
```

Now the strange thing is, I cannot even get simple patterns like `[A-z]{1,8}` to work. 
It just gives me a match, if I enter a single character, but it also matches if I enter a number and I just don't understand why.

It always prints out "no match", as soon as the input length exceeds 1. And it seems, as regex_match does not care about the pattern, as long as the input length is 1.

Why is that? I honestly can't see where I am making a mistake here.
It even matches some special characters like $ or %, but it doesn't match §.

If tried several `regex_constants` in the constructor of the regex object.

- `extended` for example gives me an error code 5 as soon as I add
  parenthesis. And even without them, it doesn't match any input with
  more than 1 character.
- `basic` doesn't throw any error, but it is still the same strange
  behaviour.
- `ECMAScript` complains with error code 4, which means brackets.

I am honestly out of ideas, why this doesn't work.

I am running Ubuntu 13.10 64bit Gnome in a virtual machine (VMWare), but I also tried it on my laptop, where it is installed as a dual-boot system.
gcc version is 4.8.1.

As this is my first question, I hope I provided enough details for you guys to help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++0x regex in GCC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716680/c0x-regex-in-gcc)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is gcc 4.8 or earlier buggy about regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12530406/is-gcc-4-8-or-earlier-buggy-about-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

gcc's regex implementation might compile, but that's about it, it is mainly [unimplemented](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.200x) in gcc 4.8 (see item 28).

Comment: Yeah, even though GCC 4.8 is fine on the core language side, it still lacks a lot on the standard library side. Unfortunately, regexes are but one known issue. :(

Comment: Okay, that explains a lot. Thanks for the information guys, I will need to check the syntax of the input "by hand", which is what I wanted to avoid in the first place.

Comment: @ThomasEizinger If you have to use gcc, you could just use boost.regex, which is pretty much what was adopted as the C++ TR1/C++11 standard library component.

Comment: Poco is another library similar to boost that I find easy to use.

Comment: PCRE is another alternative regex library (with `pcre++` as a C++ wrapper).

Comment: Since I don't have any other use for boost in my program and the problem is rather simple to solve without regex, I will go for the manual way, but thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: It kind of makes you wonder why it even compiles if it doesn't work.

Comment: Just for completeness I'll mention that the recently released version of libstdc++ has `<regex>` implemented.

Comment: give gcc 4.9 trunk a chance. regex is going to trunk last week :-) This version is not released but maybe it works as expected.