# How can I fix this C++ Regex compile error?

Tags: c++, regex, std

```
C:\Users\Hunix\AppData\Local\Temp\ccBkdVY3.o:parser.cpp:(.text$_ZNSt11basic_rege
xIcSt12regex_traitsIcEEC1EPKcj[std::basic_regex<char, std::regex_traits<char> >:
:basic_regex(char const*, unsigned int)]+0x9c): undefined reference to `std::bas
ic_regex<char, std::regex_traits<char> >::_M_compile()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

I'm getting this error when I want to compile. I used the boost::regex, but with that I had an error like this. Now I'm using the standard regex and I'm still getting the error. What's wrong? How can I fix it?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what version of g++ are you using? You may find [**this question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716680/c0x-regex-in-gcc) helpful (or depressing, depending on how you look at it).

Comment: AFAIK, g++ didn't have proper regex support until 4.9